# Given the taylor series, find the function it derives from?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Taylor series (centered at -1) is given by:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)}{n}(x+1)^n $$

1. what function centered at -1 does this series represent?
2. hints as to how I may find its interval of convergence is (-2,0)?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, with appropriate symbols Matt. My first time here actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $w=1+x$. Note that $\dfrac{n+1}{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{n}$.

So our sum is 
$$\sum_1^\infty w^n +\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}w^n.$$
The first sum will be very familiar. For the second, note that $\dfrac{w^n}{n}$ is an antiderivative of $w^{n-1}$.

For convergence, you are interested in showing that the interval is $-1\lt w\lt 1$. Ratio test will do it, except that you need to show also that we do not have convergence at $w=\pm 1$.

Comment: Left term in sum: {1/(1-w)} - 1

Comment: @student101: Indeed, and now you should be ready for right term.

Comment: right term in sum: {1/(1-w)}d/dw= 1/{(1-w)^2}

Comment: @student101: Integrate, don't differentiate. Answer looks like $\int_0^w f(t)\,dt$ for suitable $f$.

Comment: integral being -log(1-w)

Comment: @student101: $f(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$, the integral is a logarithm. Need to smoke, will be away from computer for a while.

Answer (score 1):

For the interval of convergence, consider the root test, and answer the following questions:

What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n+1}{n})^{1/n}$?

For what values of $x$ is $|x+1| < 1$?

For what values of $x$ is $|x+1| = 1$?

When $|x+1| = 1$, does the series converge or diverge?

Comment: so (1+1/n)^(1/n) converges to 1

Comment: abs(x+1)<1 for -2<x<0

Comment: at x=0, the series converges; thanks :)

Comment: at x=-2, series converges also

Comment: How can it converge at $|x+1| = 1$ when the absolute value of each tern is greater than $1$?

Comment: not sure if i'm misunderstanding but here is how i see it: abs(x+1)=1, implies x=0. Now at x=0, the series in original post reduces to SUM({n+1}/{n}); which converges to 1 as n approaches infinite.